# Accessing same android device from Different platforms

Tags: android, adb

I have windows, Ubuntu & Android platforms in the same network.

I can access the android device after connecting through adb connect `<IP>` command.

But I could access the android device through the Platform in which I have connected first. In the second platform it is showing device offline.

Is there anyway to access the android device from both windows & Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your 2 systems being "different platforms". An attempt to connect to the same `adb` devices from 2 Windows systems (or 2 Ubuntu systems for that matter) would produce the same result. `adb` was not designed to be used this way - `adbd` daemon on the device can only be connected to 1 `adb host` at a time.

Instead connect your android device to your Ubuntu system and use whatever remote access solution you prefer (x server, vnc, ssh, etc) to control it from your Windows system.